# Issues when starting docker build on windows

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

I am running trying to run a docker build on windows 10:

```
D:\mds>docker-compose --file=docker-compose.yml up -d
Starting mds_data_1
Starting mds_memcached_1
Starting mds_mongo_1
Starting mds_mysql_1
Starting mds_fc_1
Starting mds_succeed_1
Starting mds_haproxy_1`
```

But fc_1 is not starting, and when I run: `docker logs mds_fc_1`, I see:

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"/D/~mds\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f483546b2e19d0860971307b8cc813bad6ca683f3ebd90c36d89974444d7b75b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/www/applications/mds\\\" caused \\\"stat /D/~mds: input/output error\\\"\""
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"/D/~mds\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f483546b2e19d0860971307b8cc813bad6ca683f3ebd90c36d89974444d7b75b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/www/applications/mds\\\" caused \\\"stat /D/~mds: input/output error\\\"\""
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `docker ps -a`, then you can see your docker container status.

I think fc_1 is in `exited status`, because it failed with error something like `file not found error`.

please find why this error happened, then you can fc_1 can run continuously.